# How to convert an integer to character in Fortran90

Tags: string, fortran

I'm trying to mass create files dependent on where I am in a do loop, and I've tried converting an integer to a character and I'm going around in circles.

My code is along the following lines,

```
 do j=1,100,1
  if(mod(j,10)==0) then 
  datafile = "data_"//char(j)//".data"
  open(unit=1,file=datafile)
  end if 
 do i =1,1000,1
  ! some code here...
  write(1,*) info
  end do
  close(1)
 end do
```

I've tried using char() but it doesn't work, I've seen some people mention using write() but I can't get that to work either. Does anyone know how to convert an integer to a str in Fortan?

Comment: And please always use tag Fortran for all Fortran questions.

Comment: If you really want to know why the approach with `char` isn't working we could probably address that.  The duplicate is for the more important question of how to get to the end result.